# How do I map a resultset that represents a linked list using mybatis?

Tags: java, mysql, linked-list, mybatis

Currently my result set looks like this:

```
id value nextId
 1  val1   4 
 2  val2   3 
 3  val3   null 
 4  val4   2
```

This should produce a linked list object structure such as:

{id: 1, value: val1, next: -> {id: 4, value : val4, next : -> {id: 2, value: val2, next ->.....

essentially  a linked list, however I seem to be having trouble going further than 1 level deep in mybatis, is there some way i can signify that the nextId column is a reference to the id column so mybatis continues to build on the same object?

Answer (score 0):

Please use ResultHandler and populate it in java pojo.